# Jquery animate in Views slideshow

Tags: views, javascript

Is there any way to add some jQuery animations in each slide of a slider created with [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module?

Comment: can you be more specific about what kinds of transitions you are trying to achieve? something different than the transitions provide by cycle: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [Views Slideshow Xtra](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_xtra) module

> Views Slideshow Xtra is an enhancement module for Views Slideshow, providing the ability to create overlays for a Views Slideshow. HTML elements are placed in  overlays, with overlay visibility controlled by toggling the CSS display property, so that overlays are displayed with their corresponding slide. Animation of the overlay displays is also supported.